# C++ ARMA method and regression analysis

Tags: c++, statistics, regression

Is there any C++ library that implements the ARMA method and possibly its variants? I'd be good to have a mature distribution for this kind of analysis.

Comment: What do you want to do ? Sampling from an ARMA model is easy enough not to warrant any library (you just need a random generator, and you can use either C++11 or boost for this). If you want to do eg. maximum likelihood inference, then you are better off with another language, since you'll have to do a lot of things by yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any native C++ library to compute ARMA models. However, if convenience is more important to you than raw performance, you can do it indirectly:

- Use [R](http://www.r-project.org/) to compute [ARMA](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/tseries/html/arma.html) models
- Use [RCCP](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) to link C++ to R (or vice
  versa)