# AutoRegression Moving Average (ARMA) libraries for c++

Tags: c++, autoregressive-models

Is there any libraries for c++ that allows for computation of ARMA for a time series? I have not been able to find any after several search attempts.

Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of libraries for time-series analysis which support ARMA models. You have to specifically state that what you want to do.

Comment: I would like to generate expected values using ARMA. Given an input time series, I want the library to generate an estimate and the next value (forecast).

Comment: I am sorry that I was offline for a while. I hope my answer be helpful. @jamie

Comment: Thanks. I will look it up and respond to ur post soon.

Comment: @jamie were you able to find some library?

Answer (score 1):

[Cronos](https://github.com/codemedic/cronos) is an open source library written in C++ which supports ARMA models. Although it doesn't have any documentation, it seems straightforward to use.

You can also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272856/c-arma-method-and-regression-analysis) on stackoverflow.